# Bind dropdown with data table from response in JQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have Web API which returns dataset in response object. That Web API is being called from AngularJS service. The service function is called from another angular controller. How can I bind dropdowns using data tables from returned response object?

Below is my code:

Web API

```
public object getChallengeFilterData(JObject data)
{
        MatchBAL matchBAL = new MatchBAL();
        DataSet dsSeries= matchBAL.getChallengeFilter();
        return successResponse(dsSeries);
}
```

controller.js

```
angular.module("myapp").controller("challengesController", ['$scope',   'challengesService', function ($scope, challengesService) {
$scope.MatchList = [];
$scope.SeriesList = [];
$scope.SelectedMatchId = "0";
$scope.SelectedSeriesId = "0";
function init() {
    //$scope.getPlayersList();
    $scope.getMatchList();
}
$scope.getMatchList = function () {
    $scope.MatchList = [];
    challengesService.getChallengeFilterData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.SeriesList = response.data[0];
        $scope.MatchList = response.data.data[1];
    });
}
  init();
}]);
```

HTML Page

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="SelectedMatchId">
    <option value="0">Select Match</option>
    <option ng-repeat="option in MatchList" value="{{option.MatchId}}">{{option.MatchName}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Code looking fine. But is $scope.MatchList = response.data.data[1]; line correct? I think it should be  $scope.MatchList = response.data[1];. Please provide response for more detail.

Comment: Can you show the sample response from the web api call ? none of us know what your successResponse method does.